# Adding trailing text to specific lines

Tags: notepad++

I need to add a trailing thxt to lines, but only to lines which begins with a specific text.

Example:

```
AAA First Line text
BBB Second line text
```

I need to add the trailing text only to lines which begins with **BBB**, so, supposing to add "*with trailing text*", the final result will be:

```
AAA First Line text
BBB Second line text with trailing text
```

Any idea about how to obtain this?

Tried with some regular expression and substitution, but I can't find a way to impose the condition that only lines beginnig with something specific will get the trailing text

Comment: Sounds like you need REGEX. 
Check out this link for information on this
https://www.technical-recipes.com/2020/using-regex-to-find-and-replace-text-in-notepad/

Comment: RegEx is Regular Expression .. and its able to do things like this where you need a Pattern to be tested, and in this case, you want it to test for when BBB and to add trailing text to the end of that pattern.

Comment: What to do if line begins with `BBBBB` or `BBBAAA`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Notepad++ on the Replace dialog you need to click the Regular Expression radio button at the bottom right.  Then you can:

- Find: `^(BBB.*)$`
- Replace: `\1 with trailing text`

How that works is:

- `^...$` means the entire line instead of just part of it
- `(...)` means capture this text as `\1`
- `BBB.*` means BBB followed by 0 or more of any character
- `\1`    means replace this with whatever was captured earlier